# WebGL texture red and flickering on Apple devices

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, webgl, flicker

I'm currently in the progress of writing a simple WebGL application, where multiple textures are blended on top of each other.

The application works fine in Chrome, Firefox and IE on Windows, and also works on Android phones.

On Apple devices, however, the textures are red and flickering in any browser. I tested this on Safari on iPhone or Chrome and Firefox on a MacBook.

For example, the desired result is a wooden texture:

[image: Wooden texture]

However, on Apple devices, this is shown:

[image: Reddish]

There are no errors and no warnings from WebGL. What could be the issue or a hint to the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the solution was to initialize all variables used inside the fragment shader, which was not done correctly.

Comment: Can you be more specific? How were the other browsers handling uninitialized variables?

Comment: So the problem was that a variable in the shader, which should have been initialized to zero, was not initialized. In browsers where it worked (see original post), the variable was zero by default. On apple devices the value was something else, which caused the issue. Manually initializing all variables in the shader code fixed the problem.